# How to convert a file_get_contents url with authentication to a cURL request

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a script which gets some contents from a url using `file_get_contents()`

```
$auth_headers = 'Authorization: Basic '.$api_credentials."\r\n".
                    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'."\r\n";

$auth_context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => $auth_headers,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content'=> http_build_query(array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', )),
            )
        )
    );
$auth_response = json_decode(file_get_contents($auth_url, 0, $auth_context), true);
$auth_token = $auth_response['access_token'];    


$data_context = stream_context_create( array( 'http' => array( 'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$auth_token."\r\n", ) ) );

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($data_url.'&count='.$data_count.', 0, $data_context), true);
```

The above is the code I have written and working fine, for some reasons I need to change it to a cURL request. Not able to find how to add `$auth_context` and all to a cURL request.

the following I tried for cURL,

```
$url = $auth_url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {  
    echo curl_error($ch);  echo "\n";  $contents = '';
} else {  
    curl_close($ch);
}
if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
    echo "Failed to get contents.";$contents = '';
}
print_r($contents);
```

Am getting "Failed to get contents" error statement.
Any someone help me converting this to a cURL request.

**UPDATE**
I tried the following code for cURL, still same statement "Failed to get contents."

```
$fields = http_build_query(array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', ));
$url = $auth_url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":" . $api_secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields)), $auth_headers);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_headers);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {  
    echo curl_error($ch);  echo "\n";  $contents = '';
} else {  
    curl_close($ch);
}
if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
    echo "Failed to get contents.";$contents = '';
}
print_r($contents);
```

Comment: please add full code that was working with fine for you

Comment: At the very least, you forgot to set the method to POST and add the fields using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`  Also, don't try to set Content-Length manually, curl will figure this out for you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I missed the post fields. It worked after adding them.